# Partial fractions (How do I get from x to y)

Tags: fractions

how do I get from

$$\gamma * \left( \frac{\frac{\lambda_0 w}{(1+r)^t \beta^t \alpha}}{\frac{\lambda_0 w}{(1+r)^t \beta^t \alpha}-\frac{\lambda_2}{\beta^t \alpha}} \right)$$

to 
$$\frac{\gamma r w \lambda_0 \beta^t}{w \lambda_0\beta^t - \lambda_2(\beta(r+1))^t}$$

Im stuck. Any help?

Comment: Seems like $\gamma$ has disappeared somewhere ?

Comment: My bad. It's there now. Thank you.

Comment: I think $\beta^r$ shouldn't be there

Comment: It's output from Wolfram Alpha. So it should be correct.

Comment: Where is $\beta^r$ coming from? it does not even appear in the original expression.

Comment: I read $\beta^t$ not $\beta^r$. My bad. I corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All terms contain $\alpha$ in the denominator, up and down, so these cancel right away. The same holds for the $\beta^t$

Write $$\lambda_2 = \frac{\lambda_2 \cdot (1+r)^t}{ (1+r)^t}$$

The difference of fractions below then becomes

$$\frac{\lambda_0 \cdot w - \lambda_2 \cdot (1+r)^t}{(1+r)^t }$$

So the total becomes (as now both fractions have the same denominator)

$$\frac{\gamma  \lambda_0  w}{\lambda_0 w - \lambda_2(1+r)^t}$$

Comment: Thank you very much, but it still does not explain how to get from a to b.

Comment: In your last expression you can cancel the $\beta^t$ The extra $r$ seems wrong